# Google Colab custom module has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, google-colaboratory

What I am trying to do is to define a function in a custom module on Google Colab. 
I created a *.py file to define the function. It is

```
/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab/myfunc.py
```

Then I created a *.ipynb file at the same folder. It is

```
/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab/test.ipynb
```

In myfunc.py, the code is

```
def somefunc(a)
  return a*2
```

In test.ipynb, the code is

```
cd /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab
import myfunc
myfunc.somefunc(2)
```

Then it occurs error "AttributeError: module 'myfunc' has no attribute 'somefunc'"

I also used

```
   dir(myfunc)
```

in test.ipynb, which shows

```
['__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__']
```

**My function 'somefunc' is not in the attributes!!!**

This problem only occurs on Colab. I tried it on my computer and an online Jupyter notebooks. They are both working correctly.

PS: No matter whether I put an empty `__init__.py` file in the same folder or not, the problem always exists.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to adjust your `sys.path`.

Here's a complete example showing how to create a module and import it into Colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PtYW0hZit-B9y4PL978kV2ppJJPhjQua

The key line in this example for you to add, I believe, is:

```
# Add the local_modules directory to the set of paths
# Python uses to look for imports.
import sys
sys.path.append('local_modules')
```

You would need to adjust the path from `'local_modules'` to something like `/content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab`.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this, copy all you need on `/content` level:

```py
!cp -r ../drive/MyDrive/Colab .
```

and use them from there.

Answer (score -1):

I was importing some custom functions from one colab file to another &
got the same error even when the module imports are correctly done. So I just restarted my colab file & the issue got resolved.